# Javascript FOR loop, form input variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, variables, input

I am having an issue with incrementing form names to be pulled into jscript variables. `($('#p'+i+'_status'))`
There are 10 of each status. For 1 input it should be `$('#p1_status')`, so I could simply
type out p1-p10 and do it that way, however there should be a better solution to this issue right?

```
$(function() {
var status = [];

   for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
      status[i] = $('#p'+i+'_status');
   }

   if(status[i]=='Enabled'){
       --validation scripts--
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this JavaScript or [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/72bd815a(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: what error are you getting? for one, you're using `status[i]` outside of the `for` loop, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Javascript I didn't mean for the confusion of having Jscript be something different. Also, it was just edited with ($('#p'+i+'_status')) by pXL so I think that might be the issue? Using $('#p'+i+'_status') wouldn't capture the input and the if statement wouldn't process.

Comment: `I am having an issue with incrementing form names to be pulled` is that names or `id`s because `$('#p'+i+'_status');` pulls `id`s.

Comment: id's sorry once again for the confusion! >_<

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have other inputs ending with `_status`, you can use the attribute ends with selector to select them all:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[id$="_status"]').each(function(i, ele) {
        if ( !ele.disabled ) { 
             // do stuff
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "how exactly does a DOM element become a string ?" ?

Comment: @roasted - the OP's `if` statement is checking whether a DOM element equals the string `Enabled`. adeneo: maybe the inputs are checkboxes or radio inputs?

Comment: @roasted - I'm just following the OP's code, but `status[i]=='Enabled'` makes no sense, as the DOM element will never be the string 'Enabled'.

Comment: The input is a list of Enabled or Disabled at the moment.

Comment: @Caswell - Say what now ???

Comment: @caswell what you probably want is `$(this).val() == 'Enabled'`, or something like that. can you show us the html?

Comment: @adeneo, I think it should be `if( !ele.disabled )` because of `<input disabled="disabled" />`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera - that actually makes sense, as an element has no `enabled` property, and I just couldn't figure out what the string comparison was about ?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to evaluate the code in an html form with javascript validaiton. So I need to get the form information, in this case being a string from a dropdown list, and then evaluate what the string says using javascript.

EDIT: I understand I am quite new to javascript and OOP in general, I thought I had posed the question in a decent manner however it appears I have not.